# what is the abbrevation for ftok function for generating keys in IPC?

Tags: c, ipc, message-queue

I understood that ftok is the function used to generate unique keys, so that with that keys we can access the resources such as message queue in other process.

what is the ftok stands for ?

My assumption is tok stands for token. If not please correct me.

What does f stands for? is this function.

Curious to know about the naming convention followed.

Comment: "file" probably, like fopen, fclose, etc.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=define%3A+ftok&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8

Comment: in general, the 'f' is because the first parameter is a path to a file.  The actual implementation uses the lower 16 bits of the  inode number from the file location and the least significant 8 bits of the integer value given in the second parameter to generate the key.

Comment: the place to look for details on the naming conventions used are included in the set of UNIX extensions specified by the X/Open
      CAE specifications.  That document is available at: <http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009680699/toc.pdf>

Comment: 'file token' presumably.